# using val for setting an image in a div

Tags: jquery

I want to make a gallery with jQuery but I can't. My problem is when I want to make a lite-box I need to put an image from another div which is taken from a child of that div.
I am using this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".big-gal-img").val("test"); 
    });
</script>
```

I want to put an image instead of text but I can't.
Even this test is not working and I can't see any text in my page.
Please help me.

Comment: Assuming that's an image you want to set the `src` property: `$('.big-gal-img').prop('src', 'foo.jpg');`

Comment: `val()` is only used for form elements like `<input>` and `<textarea>`. If you need to change the `src` attribute of an `<img>`, use `$('.big-gal-img').prop('src', 'your_image_url');`

Comment: You need to supply more information / code...

Comment: if `.big-gal-img` is a div, you should set its html: `$('.big-gal-img').html('image_url')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will assign a image a new source file.. Change an image?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".myIMGtag").attr("src", "somefolder/myimage.jpg"); 
});
```

This will assign an image using a input as the value.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".myIMGtag").attr("src", $("#myINPUTtag").val()); 
});
```

This will assign copy the contents of one div to another

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myDiv2").html($("#myDiv1").html()); 
});
```

**Otherwise i suggest starting here:** http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_intro.asp

Comment: it worked.thanks a lot.you said every things that i needed and i even didn't asked.thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to be of help, feel free to accept my answer as well. Any other questions, edit your question or post a new one n will do best to help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `.big-gal-img` is a div (as the OP was trying to load text into it), you just need to do this:

```
$('.big-gal-img').html('image_url')
```

If `image_url` is an image in another div, you can get it like this:

```
var image_url = $('#otherDiv').html();
```